# Show line number at error when sourcing R script from command prompt

Tags: r, debugging

Consider the following `R` file (`C:\Users\Pedro\Desktop\test.R`):

```
f1 <- function() {
  print("A")
}
f3()
```

If I source this file from the R Console doing:

```
options(show.error.locations=TRUE);source('C:\\Users\\Pedro\\Desktop\\test.R')
```

then a line number is correctly printed with the error message:

[image]

However if I run the above command from the windows cmd prompt by doing:

```
R --slave --restore --no-save -e "options(show.error.locations=TRUE);source('C:\\Users\\Pedro\\Desktop\\test.R')"
```

Then there is no line number:

[image]

So my question: how can I get a line number in the error message when sourcing an R file from the windows cmd prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `keep.source=TRUE` seems to fix my problem:

```
options(show.error.locations=TRUE);source('C:\\Users\\Pedro\\Desktop\\test.R', keep.source=TRUE)
```